# How to run method inside a Model | MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

In the index file i have `_autoload` and load the libs and then i explode the url to get the wanted contoller and the model if exists. In the view i can see the model __construct() so the model is loaded but if i try to use `$this->model->test();` i get

> Call to a member function test() on a non-object

http://site.com/**about**

```
$this->request = about;
$controller = new $this->request;
$controller->loadModel($this->request);
```

Everething work ok

**Here is the Main controller **

```
class Conroller  {

    function __construct() {
        // echo 'Main controller<br />';
        $this->view = new View();
    }

    public function loadModel($name) {
        $path = 'models/'.$name.'_model.php';
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            require 'models/'.$name.'_model.php';
            $modelName = $name . '_model';
            // **here i make the object** 
            $this->model = new $modelName();
        }       
    }

}
```

**Here is the About model**

```
class about_model{

    function __construct() {
        echo 'test';
    }

    public function test() {
        $test = 'test one';
    }

}
```

**Here is the About Conroller**

```
class About extends Conroller {

   function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
       $this->model->test();
       $this->view->render('/about');
   }

}
```

Comment: Please post the final code you are using along with the entire error message.

Comment: This is pretty much all with the boot file and full error was Call to a member function test() on a non-object in the About Conroller. But i remove $controller->loadModel($this->request);  from the boot file and in the about model i add $this->loadModel('about'); and is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call `loadModel` in your `About` controller before you refer to the model:

```
class About extends Conroller {

   function __construct(){

     parent::__construct();

     $this->loadModel('about');
     $this->about->test();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked but without $this->about->test(); i use $this->model->test();. Thanks @rjz